# How to convert decimal to hexadecimal with Qt programming?

Tags: c++, qt

How to convert decimal to hexadecimal with Qt programming? Such as 69 switch to 45, 56 switch to 38 and so on... I try like this

```
QString str = QString::number(s.at(i).unicode());
bool ok;
qDebug() << str.toUtf8();
```

but failed. I need to convert this string "E8A5" ASCII switch to hexadecimal number or string.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You state that this "failed" but you don't specify how.   See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on how to ask your question in ways that get better help.   One thing you could specify is what is the _type_ of the result you want.  Do you want to end up with an ````unsigned int ```` or with a ````string```` which contains the decimal representation of a number?

Answer (score 22):

Source string:

```
QString str = QString::number(s.at(i).unicode());
```

Then:

Step 1. Convert string to integer

```
int nValue = str.toInt();
```

Step 2. Convert integer back to Hex string, using Qt

```
QString result = QString::number( nValue, 16 );
```

Step 3. Convert to uppercase (optional)

```
qDebug() << result.toUpper();
```

or all together in shorter form:

```
qDebug() << QString::number( str.toInt(), 16 ).toUpper();
```